# parse some folders in specific directory within particular names in matlab

Tags: matlab

I've written this code

```
srcFolders = dir('D:\test*');
for folder = srcFolders
path = strcat('D:\',folder);
sear = strcat(path, '\*.bmp');
srcFiles = dir(searc);
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat(path,'\',srcFiles(i).name);
    Image1= imread(filename);
    Image2 = imread('D:\\2','jpeg'); % Image 2
    x=diff(Image1 - Image2); %display the result to console
    if (x >= 0.05)
        name1 = strcat('D:\\temp2\',srcFiles(i).name);
        imwrite(Image1, name1, 'jpg'); 
        disp('Value 111111111111.')
        disp(x)
        else
            name2 = strcat('D:\\temp3\',srcFiles(i).name);
            imwrite(Image1,  name2, 'jpg'); 
            disp('Value 222222222222.')
            disp(x)
        end
    end
end
```

My problems are:

1-  When I implement my code its only views the value of `x` and writes only the first image from folder test1 to folder temp or to folder discard .

2- How can I write All images in folder test1 to folder temp or discard .

3- Then if I have folders from `test 1` to `test n` how can I repeat this process for all folders with particular name `test(i)` in a specific directory D to check every image in test folders and complete remaining procedure? Thanks...

Comment: Can you *please* format your code correctly? One statement per line, appropriate indention.

Comment: this code its written correctly and % statement just for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1,2 -There are some things that doesn't work in your code

```
  imwrite ( Image1(i), 'temp', '.jpg');
```

First of all, if you look in the [the MatLab Documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html), you can see that the format of imwrite is

```
imwrite(A,filename)
%or 
imwrite(A,filename,format)
```

On your code, you entered the folder name instead of the file name. A right way to write it could be

```
output_filename = strcat('your_path\temp\',srcFiles(i).name);
imwrite(Image1, output_filename, 'jpg'); %note that 'jpg' is facultative
                                            %and should not take a dot as you did
```

Just a detail, you wrote `Image1(i)`, which take only the i element of the image, i guess you want `Image1` instead.

3 - If you want to browse in multiple folders that have the defined pattern `test i`, you can do it this way (this is my way to do it, there are some more ways, maybe more optimal) :

Replace

```
srcFiles = dir('D:\test1\*.bmp');
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat('D:\test1\',srcFiles(i).name);
    ...
end
```

By

```
srcFolders = dir('D:\test*');
for folder = srcFolders
    path = strcat('D:\', folder.name);
    sear = strcat(path, '\*.bmp');
    srcFiles = dir(sear);
    for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
        filename = strcat(path,'\',srcFiles(i).name);
        ...
    end
end
```

Here is the full code :

```
srcFolders = dir('D:\test*');
for folder = 1:length(srcFolders)
    path = strcat('D:\',srcFolders(folder).name);
    sear = strcat(path, '\*.bmp');
    srcFiles = dir(sear);
    for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
        filename = strcat(path,'\',srcFiles(i).name);
        Image1= imread(filename);
        Image2 = imread('D:\2','jpeg'); % Image 2
        x=diff(Image1 - Image2); %display the result to console
        if (x >= 0.05)
            name1 = strcat('D:\temp2\',srcFiles(i).name);
            imwrite(Image1, name1); 
            disp('Value 111111111111.')
            disp(x)
        else
            name2 = strcat('D:\temp3\',srcFiles(i).name);
            imwrite(Image1, name2); 
            disp('Value 222222222222.')
            disp(x)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: i got this error

srcFolders = 

3x1 struct array with fields:
    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum

Comment: Actually that's not an error but a ";" that I forgot -> edited the code. Anyway, I don't understand what you mean by "store all images as its names that i mention for Image1(i)", could you be more explicit (don't understand the meaning of it) or edit your post with examples?

Comment: sir , in my test folders from test 1 for example to test n there are some images each one carry name like image 1 , image 2 ... etc i need to store these images based on its name on my folders temp or discard ,, then i do or put in this statement
output_filename1 = strcat('D:\\temp2\',srcFiles(i).name);
what i ahsa to put in output file name .... thanks

Comment: On which criteria of the name should you images be stored on temp or discard? Until now the classification was made based on the difference with a reference image

Comment: sir i has modified my code please correct to me whats you are thing i did wrong ,
i need to copy or move the images in case the difference is > 0.5 othere wise copy or move to folder discard ,
my images all in .bmp format ..... i still get error i dont know ... thanks

Comment: i got this error 
??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'struct'.Error in ==> strcat at 91 if ~isempty(str) && (str(end) == 0 || isspace(str(end)))

Comment: this my full error 
??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
Error in ==> strcat at 91
 if ~isempty(str) && (str(end) == 0 || isspace(str(end)))

Comment: sir , im not getting error now after your correction
but no any output or any writing images happened to any folders , 

or any disp message appear to , thanks

you can change x for any equation , to implement my code , i'm focused how i can parse all folders within test* names , and how we can writing images ,,, thanks

Comment: Made some changes, updated full code, hope it helps.

Comment: error .. 

Undefined variable "srcFolder" or class "srcFolder".

what i have to do now sir ,,,, thanks

Comment: thank you very very very much sir , its working correctly ...

very thanks ,,,, your code modification its great thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, don't forget to set the answer as agreed by clicking the check mark!

Comment: sir  HamtaroWarrior i asked my final question to export my result on the following link may you help me again ... thanks 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165743/writing-to-excel-sheet-based-on-image-different-using-matlab

Comment: @Ikaros What are Image1 and Images?? What are name1 and name2? !!