# Writing to Excel sheet based on image difference using matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I have some folders named `test*` from test 1 to test 100 for example, I need to print names of folders as header in first row.

Then I need to check my test image image2 with each image inside these folders if the diff bigger than 0.05 between my test image2 and every images from each folder test* will write 1 otherwise write 0. till to testn.

My code is as follow :

```
srcFolders = dir('D:\test*');
for folder = 1:length(srcFolders)
    path = strcat('D:\',srcFolders(folder).name);
    sear = strcat(path, '\*.bmp');
    srcFiles = dir(sear);
    for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
        filename = strcat(path,'\',srcFiles(i).name);
        Image1= imread(filename);
        Image2 = imread('D:\2','jpeg'); % Image 2

        x = diff( Image2 , Image1)
        % any suggestion here to get my output for printing in excel 
        if (x >= 0.05)
            xlswrite(xlsfile, srcFiles(i), ‘0’, ‘A1’);
        else
            xlswrite(xlsfile, srcFiles(i), ‘1’, ‘A1’);
        end
    end
end
```

thanks

Comment: So for each row you want to put the first case as an header (folder name), and all the other following cases or the row will be either 1 or 0 depending of the difference, is that it?

Comment: sir my role as follow , in the beginning i need to print the names of each folder test 1,,, to test n in the header of first row , then in second row ... when my compared image Image2 if get different with all images of first folder test1 greater than 0.5 its only write 1 other wise write 0 .. but in case some values greater or less than 0.5 will write last compared image value in that cell which is 0 or 1 , then continue to test2 ... test three ..

Comment: output role is look like 
first row        :[ test 1] [ test 2 ] [test 3] .................[ test n ] 
second row  : [   0    ] [     1    ] [    0   ] ................[    1     ] 
( these values 0 or 1 ) depend on different as i told .. thanks sir

Comment: I think I got it, but can make a screenshot on Excel and put it on your post so i'm sure?

Comment: sir its not allowed me to post image right now ,, due i has less reputation so i have uploaded in my drive and i submit the link to you sir 
output screen shoot in google drive ... 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4bqx8HOXD_9bGpJSl91YXZSdkU/view?usp=sharing

thanks

Comment: please sir these my requested output ... I have uploaded in another free photo share hosting .... thanks 
1- http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn5/azifallail1983/Screenshot%202015-06-27%2000.32.49_zpshd9hrgeg.png

2- http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn5/azifallail1983/Screenshot%202015-07-01%2008.45.17_zpsikdzphfx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%On every 'folder loop', increment the column range so you have 1 column by folder
%On every 'file loop', increment the row range so you have 1 row by file

xls_filename = 'foo.xls'; %The name of your xls file
xls_sheet = 'sheet_name'; % Put here the name of the sheet you want to write in

column_range = 'A' % Initialisation of the column range
srcFolders = dir('D:\test*');
for folder = 1:length(srcFolders)
    path = strcat('D:\',srcFolders(folder).name);
    folder_range = strcat(column_range, '1');
    xlswrite(xls_filename, {srcFolders(folder).name}, xls_sheet, folder_range); %Writing the name of the folder in the first row
    sear = strcat(path, '\*.bmp');
    srcFiles = dir(sear);
    row_range = '2';
    for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
        filename = strcat(path,'\',srcFiles(i).name);
        Image1= imread(filename);
        Image2 = imread('D:\2','jpeg');
        x = diff( Image2 , Image1);
        file_range = strcat(column_range, row_range);
        if (x >= 0.05)
            xlswrite(xls_filename, {'0'}, xls_sheet, file_range ); %Writing '0' in the second row
        else
            xlswrite(xls_filename, {'1'}, xls_sheet, file_range ); %Writing '1' in the second row
        end
        row_range = char(row_range + 1); %Moving to the next row
    end
    column_range = char(column_range + 1); %Moving to the next column
end
```

Comment: thanks sir i got this error 

??? Undefined variable "scrFolders" or class "scrFolders".

Comment: thanks sir its working now but some errors in writing to excel 
the following output screen  shoot of result 
on excel there are sheets named from A1 to A9 .. from A2 to A9 2nd image represent output ... 
along with this error message  in final 
??? Error using ==> xlswrite at 213
Excel returned: Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC.

1- http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn5/azifallail1983/Screenshot%202015-07-03%2002.52.15_zpswc4jxenx.png
2-  http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn5/azifallail1983/Screenshot%202015-07-03%2002.52.29_zps5g7vegbn.png

thanks for your help sir ...

Comment: Edited, put the name of the sheet you are working on

Comment: I don't have access to you googledrive picture, pls send it in another way

Comment: sir here ... also i used another free photo hosting .. thanks 

http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn5/azifallail1983/Screenshot%202015-07-03%2007.09.49_zpszi0fvl6s.png

Comment: sir in this photo ... i hope to get this output ...

http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn5/azifallail1983/Screenshot%202015-07-03%2007.23.09_zpsj4jeyx94.png

Comment: Missunderstood the type of input of xlswrite. Edited.

Comment: sir i got this error ...

??? Attempt to call constructor cell with incorrect letter case.


Error in ==> strcat at 77
scell = cell(1,n);

Comment: Can you tell me the line of the script where you get this error? I won't be able to help you without it

Comment: hello sir ,, i need only small modification , Image2 in my code i need to read images from folder named as free , so remaining thing i did well ,,, thanks .

Comment: any help please ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833406/%D9%8Bwrite-images-result-in-excel-file-based-on-template-color-histogram-comparison